# How do I make a transparent listview in android?

Tags: android

I want to make transparent list view in android. And I used many codes but these are not working. And my code is given below.

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

It is the list view code of my project. This code is working but its not show the transparent list view. So please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this,

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

or

```
android:background="#00000000"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

Comment: Hello,Both are not working.i want to this type activity.  http://media1.android-apps.com/images/pname/d/com.aman.LPSkinsPack/image2.png.  okey so please suggest me..

Comment: Why not use @android:color/transparent instead #00000000 on second option?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know wheather it is exactly work.But i hope it will help you.

```
 <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
<ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:divider="#fff"
                android:dividerHeight="0sp"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_10px"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: umesh i did used this code but its not working.ok sp lpease suggest to another suggestion .